# IIS Y la authentication basica ? Cierre de seccion

Tags: mvc, iis

miembros de la comunidad.

Resulta que implemente una aplicacion ASP.NET MVC en la organizacion , estoy utilizando la authentication basica de IIS,estuve investigando como podia cerrar la seccion despues de un usuario haberse authenticado pero no es posible.. la unica forma es cerrando el navegador. La pregunta es la siguiente:

si cierro el tab de la aplicacion obviamente no se perdera el inicio de seccion, al abrir otro tab no me volvera a pedir los credenciales existe alguna forma de que al abrir otro tab me vuelva a pedir los credenciales ? ya que no se puede crear un botton de Logout .

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes llegar a hacer es crear un botón de Log Out en el Layout principal y llamar a un action donde borres la Session que has llegado ha pasar en el formulario de acceso.Quedaría algo así:

```
public ActionResult SignOut()
        { Session["login"] = null;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda ;)

Comment: fallo mío,no leí la última parte. Tienes una idea aquí: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366820/logoff-user-when-browser-tab-page-is-closed-asp-net-mvc